# Cannot create TMX Glossary using Google.Cloud.Translate.V3 in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to expose programatically a TMX Glossary which was created in Google Cloud Platform but I receive following error:

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg) at Grpc.Core.Calls.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](CallInvocationDetails`2 call, TRequest req)
at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) at Google.Cloud.Translate.V3.TranslationService.TranslationServiceClient.CreateGlossary(CreateGlossaryRequest request, CallOptions options) at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallSync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<WithRetry>b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings) at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__1(TRequest req, CallSettings cs)
at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.Sync(TRequest request, CallSettings perCallCallSettings)
at Google.Cloud.Translate.V3.TranslationServiceClientImpl.CreateGlossary(CreateGlossaryRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
at Google.Cloud.Translate.V3.TranslationServiceClient.CreateGlossary(String parent, Glossary glossary, CallSettings callSettings)
at Sdl.Community.MtEnhancedProvider.GoogleApi.GoogleV3Connecter.CreateGoogleGlossary(LanguagePair[] languagePairs)

I'm using the latest version of Google.Cloud.Translate.V3. This is the code which I use:

```
var glossary = new Glossary
{
    Name = new GlossaryName(ProjectName, Location, GlossaryId).ToString(),
    LanguagePair = new Glossary.Types.LanguageCodePair
    {
        SourceLanguageCode = sourceLanguage,
        TargetLanguageCode = targetLanguage
    },
    InputConfig = new GlossaryInputConfig
    {
        GcsSource = new GcsSource
        {
            InputUri = GlossaryPath
        }
    }
};

var glossaryResponse = _translationServiceClient.CreateGlossary(new LocationName(ProjectName, Location).ToString(), glossary);
```

Where:
SourceLanguageCode = "ro-RO",
TargetLanguageCode = "en-GB"

I was able to create a glossary using a csv file but not using a TMX.
Can you please tell me if there is any other configuration which I need to set to the glossary in order to use a TMX file?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The stack trace you've given doesn't include the actual error message, which is the most important piece of information. Please edit that into the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for your response. The error message is: Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Failed to deserialize response message."). I've also tryied with a simple TMX file which has the source language =ro and target= en

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. I'll try to reproduce this. It sounds like a version mismatch, which would be quite odd.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for your quick reply and for investigating this issue.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this - I've successfully managed to create a TMX glossary using your code, and I've also managed to get a "normal" error when giving it a deliberately broken path. I would say that for a TMX glossary, I don't believe you should specify LanguagePair (because the TMX file has all the right information in). I'd also recommend using the `GlossaryName` property instead of `Name`, and removing the first ToString() call - and simply removing the second ToString() call entirely. Where you can work the strongly-typed resource name representations, it's best to do so IMO.

Comment: Given that at this point it's more of a bug report than a question, could I encourage you to file an issue at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet? It'll be somewhat easier to keep track of that way - and it's more suitable for back-and-forth than Stack Overflow is.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for the suggestions. I'll change the code and as you suggested and I'll come back with an update. I'll also open a bug on the GitHub.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've used the GlossaryName instead of name, I've removed the ToString() and I'm not spacify the language any more. After this changes I receive another error:Status(StatusCode=InvalidArgument, Detail="Invalid languages case: 0")

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that I wouldn't expect removing the `ToString()` parts to fix anything - it's just neater without them. That's interesting about the languages *having* to be specified, despite being in the TMX file. It looks like I'd misinterpreted some documentation anyway - TMX files are still unidirectional. So basically you were fine before, assuming your TMX file contains the appropriate source/target languages. We still need to work out what's going on with the error though :(

Comment: @JonSkeet I've open an issue https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/5393 and I've attached also the TMX file.